# Pandas: Fastest way to edit values in one column based based on the values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

Instead of relying on queries from SQL, I am trying to find ways that I can use pandas to do the same work but in a more time-efficient manner.

The problem I am trying to solve is best illustrated through the following simplified example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':list([1,2,3,4,5,6]),
                   'value':[12,8,31,14,45,12]})
```

Based on the data I would like to change the values of the "value" column when the id is 1,2,4 to 32,15,14

I managed to do this for one value with the following code:

```
df.loc[ df['id'] ==1, 'value'] = 32
```

However the problem is that the above code is very time-inefficient. So I wonder if anyone could help come up with a solution where I can update 20-30 values as fast as possible in a pandas table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin`:

```
df.loc[df['id'].isin([1, 2, 4]), 'value'] = [32, 15, 14]

df

   id  value
0   1     32
1   2     15
2   3     31
3   4     14
4   5     45
5   6     12
```